# Как программно запустить инсталлятор?

Tags: c#, com, windowsinstaller

Мы пробовали использовать ClickOnce, но с этой технологией много проблем. Однако она лучше нашей собственной технологии автообновления, написанной до попытки перехода, тем, что не предлагает пользователю стандартный визард инсталлятора, а позволяет запустить инсталляцию программно и встроить её в пользовательский интерфейс программы.

Может, такое возможно и для Windows Installer через COM? Хорошо бы ещё с отслеживанием прогресса операции. Тогда можно было бы доработать нашу собственную технологию до требуемой usability и не мучаться с ClickOnce.

Comment: А откуда его надо запускать?

Comment: В нашей программе формочка с прогресс-баром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужны автообновления из самого приложения поступают двояко:

1. создают приложение-загрузчик, которое перед запуском самого приложения смотрит, нет ли обновлений, и если есть, грузит и устанавливает,
2. создают отдельную службу (с правами на обновление), которая периодически проверяет обновления, и если есть устанавливает их.

Само обновление (если это пакет/патч msi/msp) можно стартовать с ключом quiet

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(
    "cmd.exe",
    string.Format("/c start /MIN /wait msiexec.exe /x {0} /quiet", guid));

psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process p = Process.Start(psi);

p.WaitForExit();
```

тогда это будет малозаметно для пользователя. Иной (и достаточно заморочный путь) - это [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185682(v=vs.85).aspx).